# PiVPN with Wireguard drops wifi connection

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-4, vpn, pi-hole

I have recently set up a Raspberry4 and installed pihole and pipvpn using wireguard on it. pihole serves as DNS for my VPN as well, DHCP is still configured on my local router and the raspberry is accessing the internet via wifi. The raspberry is assigned a static IP within my home network and I access the VPN from the internet via a duckdns-domain.

However, without a recognisable pattern, the wifi-connection is sometimes dumped when there are active VPN sessions, e.g. from my mobile phone or my notebook.

I did some research online and found entries about replacing *wpa-roam* with *wpa-config* in `/etc/network/interfaces`, but this is where my problems begin: This file is not existing on my setup, neither is /etc/default/ifplugd which is referenced in some other solutions to similar problems.

Any help would be appreciated, I will gladly post logs and additional information once requested/if needed, as I am new to the spheres of networking with raspberries and don't know which kind of information would be of use in this case.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: pivpn needs a static ip address. if on auto DHCP will get random ip. https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wireguard/

Comment: sorry for not being concise enough, I set a static IP within my router‘s intranet of course.

Comment: Please add additional information to the question, not in comments.

Comment: I added it, sry